# Notifee android notitication icon not working

Tags: push-notification, react-native-firebase

Notifee Notification icon not working in the notifee display notification

```
notifee.displayNotification({
        title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
        body: remoteMessage.notification.body,
        android: {
          channelId: 'android_id',
        },
      });
```

I have used so many things like, small_icon,large_icon and other ways but notification icon is not diplaying it is just showing a default image.

I also checked with AndroidManifest meta data tags, they are also not working.

Answer (score 3):

Small assets are size sensitive. So if we provide a custom image size, it may not work. It is better to generate and add using android studio 'add asset' wizard.
inside android node, we just need to add the small icon name, which is added using android studio.

```
 android: {
smallIcon: 'ic_small_icon',
          }
```

Where, the ic_small_icon, is added as a image asset through android studio.
Follow below [link](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/android/appearance#small-icons) to add android asset through android studio.